# Scrapy / Python: getting the unknown [index] of TR item

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I got this selector:

```
sel = response.xpath('//table//tr[td[@class="ad73"]]')
```

This will return selector list of TRs located in different positions of the page.

is there any way I can know the absolute index number of each TR (starting from (//TABLE/TR) so I can address them sequentially later on in another function?

Comment: Why do I want to do this? because immediately after these TR are other TRs with data that I need to scrape, but they don't have any sort of class or unique attribute to locate them

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is for Selenium -- I am not using that (I haven't mastered scrapy yet), AFAIK Selenium is an entirely different framework...

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do here, but following on your comment:

> immediately after these TR are other TRs with data that I need to scrape

I would say you need the `following-sibling` magic which does what it says:

```
sel = response.xpath('//table//tr[td[@class="ad73"]]/following-sibling::tr')
```

That will get you the following `tr` after the one you pinpointed.